# Angular 7: ng serve works, but console shows a Zone.js error and app won't load

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7, zonejs

**Backstory:** I needed to update my app from Angular 5.2.9 to 6 yesterday, and so I thought "why not go to 7 while I'm doing this." So of course that took all day, and required lots of changes to lots of files (mostly because of Rxjs), but in any case, by the end of the day I was able to do `ng serve` and have it compile with no errors!

But then when I went to `localhost:4200` to run the app, it halted on "Loading..." with the following message in the DevTools console:

```
core.js:14016 Uncaught (in promise) Error: In this configuration Angular requires Zone.js
    at new NgZone (core.js:14016)
    at getNgZone (core.js:14701)
    at PlatformRef.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.PlatformRef.bootstrapModuleFactory (core.js:14599)
    at core.js:14643
```

I've tried to make sure all my packages are up to date. `npm install` gives some errors around fsevents, but `zone` is up-to-date.

So I'm at a loss of what to do now. I don't know what the error message is really trying to tell me, or if it's even legit. I did `ng new` and inspected the generated files, and there's no "zone.js setup" code in there, so I didn't miss something like that. I feel like I was so close to having this update work, but of course if the app won't run, it's no good!
Googling for this error message didn't turn up anything useful (to me anyways).

Comment: You sir are a genius! It was commented out in my `polyfills.js` file. I don't know why that would have been necessary in 7 and not 5. If you want to make that an answer, I'll mark it correct!

Comment: Not related to the question, but for the rxjs changes, were you using the rxjs-compat package? I think it helps make you not have to update all your rxjs usage just to use the newest angular

Answer (score 6, accepted):

update every dependency in package.json to latest

```
npm i -g npm-check-updates
ncu -u
npm install
```

The error will be gone, even if you get this error . Go to `polyfill.ts` and add or uncomment :-

```
/****************************************************************************
 * Zone JS is required by default for Angular itself. */
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.


/**********************************************************************
```

Comment: I checked in the project I `ng new`'d and this line was commented out, yet the sample app worked. Any idea why zone.js would be in the polyfills file instead of in just say `angular.json`?

Comment: You can even add it in index.html as  <script>
    window['__Zone_disable_IE_check'] = true;
</script>
<script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>

Comment: Comment it out in production mode because it will have performance impact when throw error

Comment: this might have worked at some point, but today this upgrades your application to version 11

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened with my application as well, but in different context, i was adding the angular build files in a django app , the script tags included were not appropriate order , so while running 'python manage.py runserver', browser threw an error like "In this configuration Angular requires Zone.js" . so it got fixed after trying the below fixes:

first the order should be

- runtime.js
- polyfills.js
- main.js

since angular generates es5 and es2015 build files,  the script tags for es5 build files must contain 'nomodule  defer' as attribute , while es2015 to include ' type="text/javascript"'. The below screenshot was from 'index.html' of my Django app, where i was adding the angular build files.[image]